# Is it true that $S^n$ and $SO(n+1,\mathbb R)$ are homeomorphic ?

Tags: general-topology, lie-groups

Is it true that $S^n$ and $SO(n+1,\mathbb R)$ are homeomorphic ?

(Where $S^n:=\{x \in \mathbb R^{n+1} : ||x||=1\}$ and $SO(n+1,\mathbb R):=\{ A \in M_{n+1}(\mathbb R) : AA^t=I , \det(A)=1 \}$ )

Comment: No, the only spheres that admit Lie group structures are $\Bbb S^0, \Bbb S^1, \Bbb S^3$.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It is only true for $n=1$. Indeed, $\pi_1(SO(n)) = \mathbb Z/2\mathbb Z$ for $n\ge 3$, thus they cannot be spheres.

(It can be proved that $SO(3) \cong \mathbb{RP}^3$, see [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1456261/help-about-two-to-one-homomorphism-map-%CF%80s3-to-so3). Then use the fibration

$$0\to SO(n) \to SO(n+1) \to \mathbb S^{n+1} \to 0$$

one can show that $\pi_1(SO(n)) = \mathbb Z/2\mathbb Z$ for $n\ge 3$)

More directly: The dimension of $SO(n)$ is $\frac 12 n(n+1)$.

Comment: I don't understand how $\pi_1(SO(n))=\mathbb Z / 2\mathbb Z$ ; please help . And I don't know any fibration or anything , so if possible please explain in more elementary terms

Comment: Please see the edit: The dimension of $SO(n)$ is much bigger than $n-1$. @SaunDev

Comment: But does homeomorphism also preserve linear space dimension ? Does it follow form invariance of domain ?

Comment: You are right. It follows from invariance of domain. @SaunDev

Comment: Could you please explain how it follows ?

Comment: If you manifolds are homeomorphic, then they have the same dimension. @SaunDev . Both $SO(n)$ and spheres are topological manifolds.