# How would I prove the following theorem on quaternions?

Tags: abstract-algebra, algebraic-geometry, lie-groups, group-homomorphism, quaternions

The theorem states

> The map that takes $q$ to the map $[q] : x \to  q^{-1}xq$ is a 2-to-1 homomorphism from the group of unit quaternions to $SO(3)$.

How would I prove this?

Comment: See [this post](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1456261/help-about-two-to-one-homomorphism-map-%CF%80s3-to-so3) and related ones.

Comment: Do you mean $SO(4)$ instead of $SO(3)$? Anyhow, try and find the kernel of the homomorphism, if $q^{-1} x q = x$ for all $x$, i.e $q$ is in the kernel of your map we have to have $qx = xq$ for all $x$ i.e $q$ is in the center of the group of unit quarternions. What can you say about the center of the quaternion group?

Comment: @NoelLundström No, it's $SO(3)$.

Comment: @NoelLundström Also, I know it was probably just a slip, but [quaternion group](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quaternion_group) does have a different meaning. I know you were referring to the group of unit quaternions...

Comment: Isn't the quaternion group the same as the group of unit quaternions? @rschwieb

Comment: @NoelLundström Clearly not: the one I linked to is order $8$, and the group of unit quaternions is uncountable.

Comment: Oh right, obviously, my bad!

Answer (score 0):

You

1. prove that the given map satisfies the axioms of a group homomorphism; then
2. prove that the kernel is $\{-1,1\}$.

   1. To accomplish that, you can note that if $[q]$ fixes, $i, j, k$, then it is in the center of $\mathbb H$. What is the intersection of the center of $\mathbb H$ with the unit quaternions?